# Using contains in a loop for a panda series in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

<I am cleaning data from a dataframe. I set the values of the column called 'urls' in the dataframe to a panda series so I could use the replace(). Now with the cleaned data of my panda series I want to use a for loop to drop values that have the 4444 value in them that I used the replace() for. How would I make that for loop? >

```
import csv
import twint
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import nest_asyncio
import re
nest_asyncio.apply()

NWO_data = pd.read_csv("TwitterLinksNWO.csv")
NWO_data['urls'].replace('[]', np.nan, inplace=True)
NWO_data.dropna(subset=['urls'],inplace=True)
NWO_data.shape
NWO_data = NWO_data.astype({'urls': np.str}, copy=True)

urlsCleaned = NWO_data["urls"]


urlsCleaned = urlsCleaned.str.replace('https://','')
urlsCleaned = urlsCleaned.str.replace('http://', '')
urlsCleaned = urlsCleaned.str.replace('youtu.be', '4444')
urlsCleaned = urlsCleaned.str.replace('youtube', '4444')
urlsCleaned = urlsCleaned.str.replace('bitly', '4444')
urlsCleaned = urlsCleaned.str.replace('instagram', '4444')
urlsCleaned = urlsCleaned.str.replace('twitter', '4444')
urlsCleaned = urlsCleaned.str.replace('facebook', '4444')
urlsCleaned = urlsCleaned.str.replace('wwe', '4444')

if urlsCleaned.str.contains('4444'):

    urlsCleaned.dropna(subset=['urls'])
    print(urlsCleaned.head(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to remove rows contains `4444`.

```py
urlsAfterCleaned = urlsCleaned[~urlsCleaned.str.contains('4444')]
```